# Getting full response body from System.Net.WebRequest

Tags: c#, webrequest, httpwebresponse

I'm using System.Net.WebRequest to get info from some API.
When I get an error, the response contains only the basic HttpStatusCode and message, and not the full error returned.
For comparison, running the same post data and headers in a tool such as POSTMAN will return the full error from that API.

**I'm wondering if there is some property or way I can get the full error response??**

Here is the code i'm running:

```
public HttpStatusCode GetRestResponse(
    string verb,
    string requestUrl,
    string userName,
    string password,
    out string receiveContent,
    string postContent = null)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
    request.Method = verb;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
    {
        string authInfo = string.Format("{0}:{1}", userName, password);
        authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + authInfo);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(postContent))
    {
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postContent);
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        var dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
    }

    try
    {
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            if (responseStream != null)
            {
                var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                receiveContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();

                return ((HttpWebResponse) response).StatusCode;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        receiveContent = string.Format("{0}\n{1}\nposted content = \n{2}", ex, ex.Message, postContent);
        return HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
    }

    receiveContent = null;
    return 0;
}
```

When I generate a request that presents me with an error, I get in the error message: `The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.` and no InnerException, and nothing else I can benefit from out of the exception.

[Answer] @Rene pointed to the right direction and the proper response body can be acquired like this:

```
var reader = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream());
var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're catching the generic exception so there is not much room for specific info.

You should catch the [specialized exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tca6706(v=vs.110).aspx) that is thrown by the several webrequest classes, namely [`WebException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

Your catch code could be like this:

```
catch (WebException e)
{
    var response = ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response);
    var someheader = response.Headers["X-API-ERROR"];
    // check header

    if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
    {
        // protocol errors find the statuscode in the Response
        // the enum statuscode can be cast to an int.
        int code = (int) ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode;
        string content;
        using(var reader = new StreamReader(e.Response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        // do what ever you want to store and return to your callers
    }
}
```

In the [WebException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception(v=vs.110).aspx) instance  you also have access to the [`Response`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response(v=vs.110).aspx) send from the host, so you can reach anything that is being send to you.

Comment: This was actually the catch before I started meddling with it. I still can't see how I get the API-specific response that way. I've searched the object and searched again and can't find anything that's relevant

Comment: I've added how you can inspect the other stuff. maybe you could share what postman shows, so that I understand what you're looking for.

Comment: Here is the response I'm getting in POSTMAN: http://pastebin.com/uDRDesd7

and here is the headers collection: http://pastebin.com/FVzd7kWS

Comment: Actually I tried reading the ConnectStream like this: `new StreamReader(((((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response))).m_ConnectStream).ReadToEnd()` and it seems to do the trick. I'll update in a moment

Comment: `var reader = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream());
var content = reader.ReadToEnd();`
Works well :) Thanks!